# Optimal solution for cache files folder structure

Tags: caching, optimization, filesystems, filetree

I am defining the criteria to create an optimal folder structure for **cache files** on the filesystem.
The aim is to create the most performing **file hierarchy** from a filesystem perspective.

Files cached are mainly HTML pages, so they are small files, but as far as now my searches worked out that it is not the *size of files* to stress the index of a filesystem table, it is the *number of files* inside a directory.

Identifying the ideal number in 200 files per directory, I thought to create 10 subdirectories and 180 cache files, replicating this pattern in any subdirectory, but I admit it is a purely random attempt, not driven by a real knowledge of a good methodology to calculate it.

Can anyone suggest me which are the characteristics to evaluate in this decision, or share an authoritative resource speaking at an academic level about **filesystem optimization**, possibly applied to great file trees?

Comment: The hashfs (http://storageconference.org/2010/Papers/SNAPI/4.Lensing.pdf) paper from SNAPI'2010 might interest you. There we looked at a file system for such an scenario. My guess is that is is not so much the number of files in a directory, but the amount of non-cached file system metadata (dentry pages, inodes).